# Left join with group_concat is too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
users (id, firstname, lastname, etc)
users_to_groups (user_id(index), group_id(index))
```

I would like to make a query that returns records like the following:

```
firstname   lastname    groups
John        Smith       1,2,3,5
Tom         Doe         3,5
```

I use the GROUP_CONCAT function, and currently my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
     SELECT user_id, group_concat(group_id) FROM users_to_groups GROUP BY user_id
) AS i
ON users.id = i.user_id
```

It works, but it's very slow. I have 40k users and 260k records in the groups table.
Looks like the query doesn't use the index and goes through all the 260k lines for every user.

Is there any way to make it faster? It takes 3+ minutes, but I think it shouldn't.

Thanks!

Comment: How long does the inner query take to execute, if you run it on its own? Can you post the output of EXPLAIN?

Comment: Please post your explain plan for the query so people can help figure out why the index isn't used. Basically it looks like you are requesting info for ALL users (no WHERE clause anywhere), so all data must be scanned anyway. How long does the inner select take if you run it alone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, group_concat(g.group_id)
    FROM users                           u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN users_to_groups  g ON u.id on g.user_id
    GROUP BY u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not the left join, but the sub select that makes your query slow. MySQL really suck when it comes to sub select.

This is probably faster:

```
SELECT 
  u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname,
  group_concat(ug.group_id) AS groups
FROM
  users u
  LEFT JOIN users_to_groups ug ON ug.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY 
   u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
```

Comment: Awesome! It's really fast with that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Anyone knows how to add a second joined table? It's called "newsletters", and I'd like to also get it comma separated just like the groups table, keeping both, if possible. I tried adding another left join after the first one but it duplicated the two concated columns.

Comment: That's a different question altogether. But I'll give you a hint: `group_concat(DISTINCT ug.group_ID)`. It allows you to only return each id once. A subselect would be nicer in this situation, but it's still slower.